# why HashSet constructed from redis zset keeps sorted?

Tags: redis, jedis, spring-cache

In Java, HashSet is unsorted, like below:

```
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(1);
        set.add(4);
        set.add(3);
        set.add(2);
        set.add(5);
        set.forEach(e-> System.out.print(e+" "));
```

its output is :

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

When the java set coming from zset, like this:

```
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add(key, 1, 0);
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add(key, 4, 1);
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add(key, 3, 2);
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add(key, 2, 3);
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add(key, 5, 4);
Set<Integer> set = redisTemplate.opsForZSet().range(key, 0, -1);
System.out.println(set.getClass());
set.forEach(e-> System.out.print(e+" "));
```

The output is:

```
java.util.HashSet
1 4 3 2 5
```

Why at this time, the output keeps order as input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jedis does not return a pure hashSet but a LinkedHashSet, in which the elements are in ordered.

```
package org.springframework.data.redis.serializer;

public abstract class SerializationUtils {
    static <T extends Collection<?>> T deserializeValues(Collection<byte[]> rawValues, Class<T> type,
            RedisSerializer<?> redisSerializer) {
        // connection in pipeline/multi mode
        if (rawValues == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Collection<Object> values = (List.class.isAssignableFrom(type) ? new ArrayList<Object>(rawValues.size())
                : new LinkedHashSet<Object>(rawValues.size()));
        for (byte[] bs : rawValues) {
            values.add(redisSerializer.deserialize(bs));
        }

        return (T) values;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ZSET is ordered by the score, not the key of the members in the ZSET. So in your example:

```
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add(key, 1, 0);
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add(key, 4, 1);
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add(key, 3, 2);
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add(key, 2, 3);
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add(key, 5, 4);
```

`1` has a score of `0`, and `5` has a score of `4`. If you changed this to:

```
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add(key, 1, 1);
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add(key, 4, 4);
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add(key, 3, 3);
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add(key, 2, 2);
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add(key, 5, 5);
```

You should get the expected result.

Comment: Yes I know the features of zset. But what is confusing me is the java hashSet. The java set instance should contain no score information, why it's still ordered?

Comment: Java set doesn't guarantee ordered entries, you might be seeing a ordered output in this instance, but you can't rely on it and write a business logic.